# Flask dynamic urls how to use url_for()?

Tags: python, flask

I want to use dynamic url with blueprint,but I don't know how to use url_for() in templates.The next is some code:

```
site = Blueprint('wulwxy',__name__,url_prefix='/<url_slug>')
@site.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_user_url_slug(endpoint, values):
    g.url_slug = values.pop('url_slug')

@site.url_defaults
def add_user_url_slug(endpoint, values):
    values.setdefault('url_slug', g.url_slug)

@site.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('wulwxy/wulwxy.html')

@site.route('/infor')
def infor():
    return render_template('wulwxy/infor.html')
```

The templates:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('g.url_slug.index')">hello<a>
```

there is a error:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'g.url_slug.index'. Did you mean 'wulwxy.index' instead?
```

when I use

```
{{ url_for('wulwxy.index') }}
```

the error

```
ttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'url_slug'
```

now I only can use '/wulwxy'  to link '127.0.0.1:5000/wulwxy'

Anybody can help me?thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208488/using-url-for-across-blueprints

Comment: @brunsgaard Thank you